# New lines (\r\n) are not working in email body

Tags: php, email, newline, content-type

I am using PHP `mail()` function:

```
    $to      = 'AAAA <postmaster@xxx.xx>';
    $subject = 'BBBB';
    $message = "CCCC\r\nCCCC CCCC \r CCC \n CCC \r\n CCC \n\r CCCC";
    $headers = 'From: DDD<postmaster@xxx.xx>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"; format=flowed \r\n";
    $headers .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable \r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

When I receive this email it looks like this:

```
CCCC CCCC CCCC CCC CCC CCC CCCC
```

I would expect something like this:

```
CCCC
CCCC CCCC CCC 
CCC 
CCC 
CCCC
```

It works fine without [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) HTTP header. How can I make *new lines* and still use my "Content-Type" declaration?

Comment: text/html !== plain text - if you want new lines in text/html, you use `<br />`

Comment: I used text/plain instead text/html and everything works as expected. thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Newline showing up on screen but not in email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578174/newline-showing-up-on-screen-but-not-in-email)

Comment: My problem was that outlook decided that 'extra line breaks in this message was removed'

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You need to use a `<br>` because your `Content-Type` is `text/html`.

It works without the `Content-Type` header because then your e-mail will be interpreted as *plain text*. If you really want to use `\n` you should use `Content-Type: text/plain` but then you'll lose any markup.

Also check out this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578174/newline-showing-up-on-screen-but-not-in-email).

Comment: Would the `<pre>` tag work as well? Creating both a text and HTML version of the email, wouldn't just wrapping the text with `<pre></pre>` tag be best / less hacky than replacing `\n` with `<br />`?

Comment: @AnthonyChuinard <pre></pre> worked for me!

Comment: <pre></pre> will allow your text/html body to include some Preformatted text and still conserve the Html tags for the rest of the content.   <pre>CCCC\r\nCCCC CCCC \r CCC \n CCC \r\n CCC \n\r CCCC</pre>

Answer (score 44):

If you are sending HTML email then use **<BR>** (or **<BR />**, or **</BR>**) as stated.
If you are sending a plain text email then use **%0D%0A**
\r = **%0D**  (Ctrl+M = carriage return)
\n = **%0A**  (Ctrl+A = line feed)

If you have an email link in your email,
EG

```
<A HREF="mailto?To=...&Body=Line 1%250D%250ALine 2">Send email</A>
```

Then use **%250D%250A**

%25 = %

Answer (score 10):

You need to use `<br>` instead of `\r\n` . For this you can use built in function call [nl2br](http://us.php.net/nl2br)
So your code should be like this

```
 $message = nl2br("CCCC\r\nCCCC CCCC \r CCC \n CCC \r\n CCC \n\r CCCC");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use `content-type: text/html` you need to put a `<br>` because your message will be threated like an **html file**.

But if you change your `content-type` to `text/plain` instead of `text/html` you will be able to use `\r\n` characters.

Answer (score 5):

Using 
`<BR>`
is not allways enough. MS Outlook 2007 will ignore this if you dont tell outlook that it is a selfclosing html tag by using

```
 <BR />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add new line character in text/plain content type  using **%0A** character code.

For example:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=Hello%20again&body=HI%20%0AThis%20is%20a%20new%20line"/>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k923ddom/1/)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
$message  = nl2br("
===============================\r\n
www.domain.com \r\n
===============================\r\n
From: ".$from."\r\n
To: ".$to."\r\n
Subject: ".$subject."\r\n
Message: ".$_POST['form-message']);
```

Answer (score 1):

for text/plain text mail in a mail function definitely use PHP_EOL constant, you can combine it with 
 too for text/html text:

```
$messagePLAINTEXT="This is my message."
. PHP_EOL .
"This is a new line in plain text";

$messageHTML="This is my message."
. PHP_EOL . "<br/>" .
"This is a new line in html text, check line break in code view";

$messageHTML="This is my message."
. "<br/>" .
"This is a new line in html text, no line break in code view";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
' '
```

space was missing in my case, when a blank space added `' \r\n'` started to work

Answer (score 0):

Another thing use "", there is a difference between "\r\n" and '\r\n'.

Answer (score 0):

"\n\r" produces 2 new lines while "\n","\r" & "\r\n" produce single lines if, in the Header, you use `content-type: text/plain`.

Beware: If you do the Following php code:

```
    $message='ab<br>cd<br>e<br>f';
print $message.'<br><br>';
    $message=str_replace('<br>',"\r\n",$message);
print $message;
```

you get the following in the Windows browser:

```
ab
cd
e
f

ab cd e f
```

and with `content-type: text/plain` you get the following in an email output;

```
ab
cd
e
f
```

Answer (score 0):

OP's problem was related with HTML coding. But if you are using plain text, please use "\n" and not "\r\n".

My personal use case: using mailx mailer, simply replacing "\r\n" into "\n" fixed my issue, related with wrong automatic Content-Type setting.

Wrong header:

```
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.4 7/29/08
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Correct header:

```
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.4 7/29/08
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

I'm not saying that "application/octet-stream" and "base64" are always wrong/unwanted, but they where in my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->isHTML(true);
```

Insert this code after working
all html tag like

```
<br> <p> in $mail->Body='Hello<br> how are you ?<b>';
```