# Plain text email next line doesn't work even with "\r\n"

Tags: php, email, pear, pear-mail

Here is my code in php mail:

```
<?php
include_once("Mail.php");

$From = $_POST['enquiryemail'];
$To = $row2['email'];
$Subject = "An enquiry";
$Message = "This enquiry is created by: ".$_POST['enquiryname']."\r\nOrganization: ".$row['orgname']."\r\n Telephone Number: ".$_POST['telenum']."\r\nE-mail address: ".$_POST['enquiryemail']."\r\nMessage: ".$_POST['detail'];
address: ".$_POST['enquiryemail']."\r\nMessage: ".$_POST['detail'];
$Host = "smtp.test.com";
$Username = "";
$Password = "";

$Headers = array ('From' => $From, 'To' => $To, 'Subject' => $Subject);
$SMTP = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $Host, 'auth' => false,
'username' => $Username, 'password' => $Password));

$mail = $SMTP->send($To, $Headers, $Message);
```

and here is the result which "\r\n" doesn't work for 2 lines in the middle:

This enquiry is created by: testing
Organization: testing  Telephone Number: 123456 E-mail address: test@hotmail.com
Message: test

Any idea how to make this works? Thanks.

Comment: Outlook likes to strip line breaks out. There should be an option to show line breaks. You can use <br /> instead that won't be strip.

Comment: Show the command you are using to send the email (I'm not willing to presume you have set the content-type header).  PHP_EOL is the end of line for the platform running PHP.

Comment: I just update the question with all the details, thanks.

Comment: @Annie You have a syntax error in your code.  Can you clean up the code?  And, show us the full e-mail source that gets sent with headers.

Comment: Hi Brad, I can send email through this code, so I think the syntax is fine just the line break part is not working.

Comment: The source of the actual message would be helpful for diagnostics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specifically declare content type to **html** to use html statements

```
$message_string = "\r\n";
$message_string .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"';
$message_string .= "\r\n";
$message_string .= $Message;
```

Now your break statements will take effect.

Comment: is this the solution?

Comment: Yes, in you $Message variable, add $message_string content before the actual message itself. and this should work.

Comment: Yes and any other html based styling.

Comment: how to add smpt setting in html mail?

Comment: just like you would do for plain text email

Comment: should I use $mail = $SMTP->send($To, $Headers, $message_string);? Do I need to use <html> in the body?

Comment: I just try and switch to html. Then the “\r\n” works without switching to <br>, thanks!.

Answer (score -2):

You need to `<br>` instead of `\r\n` because your content-type is text/html.
Same question here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063312/new-lines-r-n-are-not-working-in-email-body)

Comment: I tried <br> before and it just shows <br> in email.

Comment: Nowhere is this e-mail specified as HTML.  It isn't even encoded properly for that.