# Newline in Javascript doesn´t work - \n \r <br>

Tags: php, html, email, line-breaks

I have a booking form which uses a function (attendees_full_info) to output all the data entered into an e-mail. Now the formatting bothers me because all labels and input are in one line.

I have the following code:

```
if(is_array($reg_form) and count($reg_form))
        {
            foreach($reg_form as $field_id=>$value)
            {
                // Placeholder Keys
                if(!is_numeric($field_id)) continue;

                $type = $reg_fields[$field_id]['type'];

                $label = isset($reg_fields[$field_id]) ? $reg_fields[$field_id]['label'] : '';
                if(trim($label) == '') continue;

                if($type == 'agreement')
                {
                    $label = sprintf(__($label, 'mec'), '<a href="'.get_the_permalink($reg_fields[$field_id]['page']).'">'.get_the_title($reg_fields[$field_id]['page']).'</a>');
                    $attendees_full_info .= $label.': '.($value == '1' ? __('Yes', 'mec') : __('No', 'mec'))."\r\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    $attendees_full_info .= __($label, 'mec').': '.(is_string($value) ? $value : (is_array($value) ? implode(', ', $value) : '---'))."\r\n";
                }
            }
        }
```

The result is the following:

[image: Result 1]

Here's what I've already tried. After the ":" i have inserted \r\n or only \n. But this does not work.

example:

```
if($type == 'agreement')
                {
                    $label = sprintf(__($label, 'mec'), '<a href="'.get_the_permalink($reg_fields[$field_id]['page']).'">'.get_the_title($reg_fields[$field_id]['page']).'</a>');
                    $attendees_full_info .= $label.': \r\n'.($value == '1' ? __('Yes', 'mec') : __('No', 'mec'))."\r\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    $attendees_full_info .= __($label, 'mec').': \r\n'.(is_string($value) ? $value : (is_array($value) ? implode(', ', $value) : '---'))."\r\n";
                }
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I can adapt the code accordingly?

Comment: Are you sending it in html format or plain/text?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New lines (\r\n) are not working in email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063312/new-lines-r-n-are-not-working-in-email-body)

Comment: Yes it is in html format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From other parts of your code (e.g. where you create `<a href` text and so on), it looks like your email is intended to be a HTML-formatted email.

Assuming that's correct, then it's expected that newline (`\n` or `\r\n`) characters won't work - HTML does not recognise them as formatting characters. It's likely you'd actually be seeing them as part of the finished output, in fact.

In HTML, you can specify a line break with the `<br/>` tag instead. Run this demo to see it in action:

```html
Line 1<br/>Line2
```