# How to Add Line Breaks to Mailgun Template

Tags: go, mailgun

I am using mailgun Templates with Go to send emails. However when the text in my template fields contain `\n` no newline is added. My basic code looks like the following:

```golang
message := m.mg.NewMessage(sender, subject, body, recipient)
message.SetTemplate("my-template")
_ = message.AddTemplateVariable("myText", event.Text)
// ... Code for sending
```

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063390/9609442) about sending mail with newlines, however when I implement it like the following:

```golang
_ = message.AddTemplateVariable("myText", strings.ReplaceAll(event.Text, "\\n", "<br />"))
```

The email contains `<br />` text in the body but no newlines.

I also tried adding the following field in the css of my template: `white-space: pre-wrap;` but still there was no break. Thanks for any help with adding a newline to a Mailgun Template with Golang.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use triple-stash in your template instead of double-stash

```
{{var1}} -> {{{var1}}}
```

Comment: This is a security concern if the content to display is something the user typed via an HTML form, isn't it ?

Comment: no at all @Flobesst, because almost email platform only support some simple HTML tag.